# Using WCS DEM data for make slope and aspect maps in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, slope, wcs, aspect

I need to do several slope and aspect analyses (hundreds).

Instead of downloading an ASCII for each location, I want to extract/clip the elevation data from wcs and do the analysis.

This is the WCS service (DEM of Spain):

https://servicios.idee.es/wcs-inspire/mdt?version=2.0.1&request=GetCapabilities&service=WCS

Is there any way to do this on QGIS?